# What does the "$" symbol mean in Mathematica programming?

Tags: functions, programming, symbols

I cannot find any reference to the $ in the Mathematica documentation, yet I frequently see it used, especially on StackExchange.

Answer (score 6):

It has no built-in meaning, you are free to assign it a value:

```
In[23]:= $ = 3

Out[23]= 3
```

It is common to name package constants with a symbol starting with `$`, but this is just a convention.

Comment: I think "constant" is not quite the best word for it. I'd rather say "global variables that are not supposed to be messed with by the user". E.g., `$ContextPath` is meant to be change frequently -- alas only by the system, not by the user.

Answer (score 4):

It has no inherent meaning, but it is used by convention as a prefix for many system parameters and special-purpose symbols. Look at

```
Names["System`$*"]
```

It is also used to "localize" variables in Module. Look at

```
Module[{x}, x]
```